# How to add a new column in the table if the table has a constraint on it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a new column with these details.

```
ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL
```

Currently, my SQL script is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlightTotal]
(
    [FlightID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUTC] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [ManualT] [smallint] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [FlightTotal_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FlightID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [UD01]
) ON [UD01]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FlightTotal] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_FlightTotal_CreatedUTC]  
        DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) FOR [CreatedUTC]
GO
```

Do you have any idea how to alter the current table so that I can insert the new column?

Comment: just use `alter table yourtable add column ....`

Comment: If your table already have rows in it, you can't add a `NOT NULL` column without specifying a `DEFAULT` value

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, my table has rows in it so how to do it??

Comment: as stated in you need to specify a `DEFAULT` value example : `ALTER TABLE [FlightTotal] ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`. OR add as a nullable column, update the table and set the value accordingly then change it to `NOT NULL`

Comment: @Squirrel: you should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FlightTotal] 
ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [DF_Revenue] DEFAULT 0

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FlightTotal] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Revenue]
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. Since can't add a new column when there are rows in the table, it is much better to use a default constraint then drop it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you should wait to drop the constraint until you can confirm that anyone writing to the table is supplying a value for the new column. Otherwise, they'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column to table

```
ALTER TABLE [FlightTotal] ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL
```

If the table already have some rows, you can't add a `NOT NULL` column. You need to specify a `DEFAULT` value

example :

```
ALTER TABLE [FlightTotal] ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

OR

add as a nullable column,

```
ALTER TABLE [FlightTotal] ADD [Revenue] decimal(10,6)
```

update the table and set the value accordingly

```
UPDATE [FlightTotal]
SET    [Revenue]   = {some value}
{WHERE  condition if any}
```

then change it to NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE [FlightTotal] ALTER COLUMN [Revenue] decimal(10,6) NOT NULL
```